# Facebook Safety Check API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an app that needs to be notified in case the Facebook Safety Check is activated.
Basically I need to gather about the context (what, when, where, ..) and also list the users "safety" status.
Is there a way to query the Safety Check through the Facebook API ?
Is there a way to simulate a Safety Check activation for testing purpose ?

Thanks for your help